# How to get ::after to work on an anchor element

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to get a right triangle to show up on a button on a WordPress menu. The problem is the after pseudo-element doesn't show up! Here is the page and the buttons are the last two in the orange menu:

http://s1.mrfoxcomposting.com/

```
#masthead .menu-primary-inner li.menu-item-button.menu-item a:after {
    transition: 200ms;
    content: "\f0da";
    font-family: 'uncodeicon' !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 42%;
    right: 31px;
    width: auto;
    color: white;
}
```

I have read the specs for ::after, with the content set it should show up but it doesn't, can anyone see why the :after pseudo-element does not show up in Google Chrome in this case? I am very thankful for any assistance provided!! It seems like I am applying the styles correctly, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Perhaps the font family name is misspelled? Shouldn't it be "'uncode-icons"?

Comment: Worth a shot... try `::after`. Technically speaking, pseudo elements are supposed to have 2 colons... versus pseudo classes that only have 1.

Comment: You should post your HTML also, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to add height. Maybe the background is white, so the triangle is camouflaged. Hard to tell with the limited code you've provided.

Comment: I put the link to the page itself in, then I edited and must have accidentally removed it, here is the full page: http://s1.mrfoxcomposting.com/

Comment: Your `content` values for the `::after` pseudo-elements for those two buttons are `""` and `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a class conflict, although I could not find the style that was causing the conflict, changing the class name to 'menu-item-button-ex' fixed it.